# Segmentation fault (core dumped) with optuna

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, optuna

I'm running a python script in the command line with `python3 CTGAN_noscale.py --database_name CTGAN_noshift` and receive the following error (with faulthandler):

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007f57e97fe700 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>

Thread 0x00007f593db07740 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 145 in backward
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 245 in backward
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ctgan/synthesizers/ctgan.py", line 374 in fit
  File "CTGAN_noscale.py", line 140 in objective
  File "CTGAN_noscale.py", line 162 in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/optuna/_optimize.py", line 216 in _run_trial
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/optuna/_optimize.py", line 162 in _optimize_sequential
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/optuna/_optimize.py", line 65 in _optimize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/optuna/study.py", line 401 in optimize
  File "CTGAN_noscale.py", line 162 in run_CTGAN
  File "CTGAN_noscale.py", line 210 in <module>
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It seems that the problem is somehow with optuna.
The weird part is that everything worked fine on another server, after changing the server it crashed like this.

**Update**

I found out that the the problem doesn't occur when I don't use a docker container OR use a docker container without GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by rebuilding a new image and derived a container from this image. In this container somehow the error didn't appear anymore.